# Send automated push notifications in the same time using urbanairship

Tags: urbanairship.com

I want to send every day in the same time push notification using urbanairship.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

here what does 'same time' actually reflects..a regular synchronous time on clock or delta asynchronous time?

Comment: For exmaple I want to send notification every day at 8PM (in each country it will be 8PM)